# Override Interface in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have uncovered a defect in my Magento 2.1.3 install and have narrowed it down to a key relationship in my database that is an open ticket within the Magento community.

Long story short, the only way I can seemingly fix the issue is by changing a constant within a core Magento file. Because Magento 2 uses dependency injection, I am trying to overwrite an interface that has the constant that I need to change.

My problem lies in that I have been trying to override that interface, as I have with Models, Layouts, etc for other modifications, yet nothing has seemingly worked. Below is the few files that I believe are relevant to this issue. I have also search high and low to understand better what an interface is in PHP and how it relates to the Magento 2 ecosystem but nothing has helped.

Note: I pulled out our vendor name and replaced with [vendorname] for some privacy. Also I have the needed registration.php file in place and setup:upgrade runs without errors.

app/code/[vendorname]/[vendorname]Customer/Api/AddressMetadataInterface.php

```
namespace Magento\Customer\Api;

/**
 * Interface for retrieval information about customer address attributes metadata.
 * @api
 */
interface AddressMetadataInterfaceRev extends MetadataInterface
{
const ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS = 6;

const ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS = 'customer_address';

const DATA_INTERFACE_NAME = 'Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface';
}
```

app/code/[vendorname]/[vendorname]Customer/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface" type="[vendorname]\[vendorname]Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface" />
</config>
```

With this code. I get the following error when trying to run setup:di:compile

`Fatal error: Cannot declare interface Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface, because the name is already in use in /Users/[username]/Sites/[sitename]/app/code/[vendorname]/[vendorname]Customer/Api/AddressMetadataInterface.php on line 13`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change the namespace of your preference class to match your module's namespace instead of Magento's namespace. Then you should make your class extend the original (`\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface`) so you only need to override the constants that need changed:

**app/code/[YourVendor]/[ModuleName]/Api/AddressMetadataInterface.php**

```
namespace [YourVendor]\[ModuleName]\Api;

/**
 * Interface for retrieval information about customer address attributes metadata.
 * @api
 */
interface AddressMetadataInterface extends \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface
{
    const ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS = 2;

    const ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS = 'customer_address';

    const DATA_INTERFACE_NAME = 'Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface';
}
```

### Important Note

Due to the nature of constants and how you can access their values without instantiating the class (`\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface::DATA_INTERFACE_NAME`), I don't know if this is going to solve your problem since every use case I just mentioned references the original class and not your override. As far as I knew class preferences only work when a class name is requested through the object manager or via Dependency injection. Might be worth some investigating.